# Reporting tools that allow to abstract the document's actual geometry

Tags: latex, jasper-reports, report, typesetting

We are using Jasper Reports to generate reports from our application, based on Oracle DBMS.

The thing works fine, but it is likely we're going to use different paper formats, languages and orientations for the same document, or to add columns and other elements, or have the elements' contents change size.

Doing this in iReport/Jasper isn't easy AFAIU. 
If something doesn't work you have to move or resize elements by hand, checking they're  of appopriate size and position.

When I was a student I would use LaTeX for typesetting and it could easily handle "reshaping" well. Isn't there something like that?

I heard BRIT doesn't follow the "pixel position" paradigim of Jasper and Pentaho, and as such it strive to handle positioning and, possibily sizing, alone, after the user had specified the document's abstract structure, i.e. what elements are there and their relative position.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention: we are looking for a solution that involves as little code as possible. The reasons are manifold, but the most important are:

- first: avoid learning another library (we managed to stay away from Jasper's and liked it).
- second: giving a tool that even those that aren't programmers, or hardcore ones, could manage. 
  The lower the entry barrier the better. 
  For example I know people in the humanities that can pick up LaTeX decently. They could even digest iReport. I don't know of anyone who can do the same with real-world Java.

Comment: Have you looked into using [DynamicJasper](http://dynamicjasper.com/)? It can get complicated if you are doing anything complex, but for a majority of reports it works pretty well.